# Health checks of Private Instance in Target Groups Shows as unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, nlb, aws-vpc, amazon-elb

I created a network load balancer(internal) to point to the private servers in the VPC, as per documentation i have done the below steps:

- Configure Security Groups to allow traffic from Client IP address as well as VPC CIDR Blocks.

But after implementing the above procedure, Target Group says that the private server is unhealthy. Below is my Target Group Config:

Protocol            TCP
Port                traffic port
Healthy threshold   3
Unhealthy threshold 3
Timeout             10
Interval            30

Please assist me here

Comment: can you share your security group configuration? As you tag NLB, NLB don't have Security Group but its use the SG of the desired instance.

Comment: yes i opened up the inbound rules of private instance SG to 0.0.0.0/0 (port 80), but still no luck..still shows as unhealthy

Comment: okay then the check on instance is port occupied, make custom health route if possible in your application, if still looking for futher detail check this blog https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/ts-elb-healthcheck.html

Comment: yes got the reason, the web server service was down due to to some reasons. When restarted the service things started working fine.

Comment: thats good do the basic operation before you post question...just suggestion ;)